# My iPhone locks up

Tags: ios

Software:  XCode 6.2 beta

Here's my problem: I have two apps out for sale. I created a lite version of one of the apps and have it loaded on my phone for testing. The lite version works fine, the ads run, and the testing of the in-app purchases are successful.

Here is where the problems arise: When I have the lite version on my phone and I try to open one of my other apps that is out for sale, my phone shorts out. The "for sale" app freezes on the launch image and I have to do a soft restart on my phone to get it to work. From that point, my app that is out for sale is gone from the folder it was in but it still exist in "Settings>Usage".  When I find it in the usage list the app's icon is gone and when I click the blank icon the detail page shows the app icon from my test app (the lite version).

This problem has happened in reverse as well. When I open the lite version, it freezes on the launch image.

Comment: Having the same issue but I don't believe it is this exact one.

Answer (score 0):

After stepping away from my problem for a few hours I realized what I did was reused a bundle identifier.  Once I changed this all of my problems were resolved